# How can I increase the tileset limit in RPG Maker VX?

Tags: rpg, rpg-maker-vx, tilesets

In RPG Maker VX, the default setup allows you to have five tilesets for the map layout. 
Is there a way I can increase this limit?

I know it's possible to make "fake" tiles by using events overlaid on the real tiles to show different images. However, this is a huge hassle to setup, and isn't a very clean way of creating the game; I'm hoping there is another way.

Comment: Long time ago I used RPG Maker, so I can't remeber everything. But, I think its impossible to bypass the map editor tileset limit. You can try via RGSS.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like RPG Maker VX is overly restrictive with this when compared to other versions, and there is no out-of-the-box way to do it. However, there are at least community-made scripts, such as [SwapXT](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605121048/http://www.rpgmakervx.net/index.php?showtopic=33958) ([download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lodestone2d/files/SwapXT/SwapXT.exe)), that allow you to work around the limitation.